# How can I install jack2 on nixos?

Tags: nixos, nix

I have been trying to follow the instrucitons here: https://nixos.wiki/wiki/Using_JACK_with_PulseAudio

```
error: attribute 'pulseaudio' missing, at /etc/nixos/configuration.nix:17:33
(use '--show-trace' to show detailed location information)
```

I receive the above when trying

```
  hardware.pulseaudio.package = pkgs.pulseaudio.override { jackaudioSupport = true; };
```

I've also found this github commit - but I don't think it's in the nixos channel yet? https://github.com/NixOS/nixpkgs/blob/f4811789605ee3fb1c069fd6c569aae32cd27d1e/pkgs/misc/jackaudio/default.nix

Answer (score 1):

It looks like pulseaudio is not installed, I would do the following.

Add to your configuration:

```
hardware.pulseaudio.enable = true;
hardware.pulseaudio.support32Bit = true;    ## If compatibility with 32-bit  
    applications is desired.
```

You may need to add users to the audio group for them to be able to use audio devices:

```
users.extraUsers.alice.extraGroups = [ "audio" ... ];
```

More info: [Here](https://nixos.wiki/wiki/PulseAudio)

Answer (score 0):

I think I had to update the channels,

I've added myself to the "audio" groups as mentioned by @Michael.

Add this to my config:

```
let 
  hardware.pulseaudio.package = pkgs.pulseaudio.override { jackaudioSupport = true; };
in
{
...
```

I had stop pulseaudio `systemctl --user stop pulseaudio` and then kill the process `pkill pulseaudio`.

I had to install these packages:

```
 unstable.jack2
 libjack2
 qjackctl
```

Add this file:

```
cat ~/.config/pulse/client.conf
daemon-binary=/var/run/current-system/sw/bin/pulseaudio
```

And then using qjackctl set the jackd path to `jackdbus` and enable the two settings (Setup > Misc) for `Enable D-Bus interface` and `Enable JACK D-Bus interface`.

Not sure if all the above is required and optimal - but it works on initial inspection.